# Rhino JS / ScriptEngine from Java - integers in, doubles out?

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I'm trying out Rhino to embed Javascript in Java.  I noticed that when I eval a script that adds two ints together in Javascript, the result comes back as a Double.

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
engine.put("x", 3);
engine.put("y", 4);

assertEquals(3, engine.eval("x")); // OK
assertEquals(4, engine.eval("y")); // OK
assertEquals(7, engine.eval("x + y")); // FAILS, actual = (Double) 7.0
```

So why does the `x + y` expression return a double instead of an int?

Is Javascript itself doing some type promotion I don't understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fun fact of the day: All numbers in javascript (ECMAScript) are double-precision.

> The Number type has exactly 18437736874454810627 (that is, 264−253+3)
>   values, representing the double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754
>   values as specified in the IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point
>   Arithmetic, except that the 9007199254740990 (that is, 253−2) distinct
>   “Not-a-Number” values of the IEEE Standard are represented in
>   ECMAScript as a single special NaN value.

http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-8.1.5

Comment: ok - but then why do some numbers come back as ints and others as doubles?

Comment: If I had to take a guess it has something to do with floating point approximation. When Rhino gets a nice integer it gives it a stright value of `4.0000000000000` However, `4.0000000000000 + 3.0000000000000 ` may become `7.0000000000001`. JavaScript being nice just gives you 7, but Java knows better and someplace in the translation you will get 7.0

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript only has one numerical type - [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) which is analogous to the Java [Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) type. I expect the engine is coercing the type to `Number` to perform the arithmetic.