# indexOf function on ArrayList<Integer> not work in JSR 223 (Rhino scripting engine)

Tags: java, arrays, rhino, jsr223

I am try use array list of integer and check var exist in it.
It work  on array of string but not work on array of integers.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);

    List<String> lists = new ArrayList<String>();
    lists.add("1");
    lists.add("2");

    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    engine.put("list", list);
    System.out.println(engine.eval("list.indexOf(1)"));
    //print -1 , Why ?

    engine.put("lists", lists);
    System.out.println(engine.eval("lists.indexOf('1')"));
    //print 0
}
```

What wrong with code?

Comment: Looking at code  : Your using a array list of Objects not of integers as you say you are. Do not know what the spec says about this but are you sure it should work?

Comment: @tgkprog There are integers in it though. Regardless, at run time the type argument no longer exists. It is simply a `List`, in both cases.

Comment: Yes I was hoping Amigo will realize that and next logical thing - file a bug with the Rhino team.

Comment: @tgkprog My mistake, copy wrong code. But with list of Integer example give same results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a subclass of `ArrayList` to get more information about what is happening:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>() {
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        System.out.println(o.getClass());
        return super.indexOf(o);
    }
};
```

If you modify your first ArrayList to use this subclass, you'll see that `indexOf` is being called with a `java.lang.Double`, but your numbers are being boxed as `Integer`s when storing them in the list.

One possible work around is to call indexOf with a boxed `Integer`, which you can create in Javascript like this:

```
System.out.println(engine.eval("list.indexOf(java.lang.Integer.valueOf(1))"));
// now outputs 0
```

Of course, you would probably want to encapsulate that in a function, to avoid having to type so much every time. But even doing that, it's tedious and error-prone, which is why I called it a work around.

Comment: [And I don't believe there is a way to fix that.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528573/rhino-js-scriptengine-from-java-integers-in-doubles-out)

Answer (score 0):

You can try telling javascript the specific type...

```
System.out.println(engine.eval("list.indexOf(new java.lang.Integer(1))"));
```

I doubt that will be compatible with many other JS engines, but it works for this case.